# Mongoose near maxDistance doesn't seem to have an effect

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, geojson

I'm trying to write a simple query in Mongoose that returns a number of nearby results that all have GeoJSON properties. However, I'm getting a different number of results from my Mongoose script to that of a query directly in mongo.

Here's a raw Mongo script:

```
var conn = new Mongo(),
    db = conn.getDB("my_db"),
    collection;

collection = db.my_moodels.find({
  geo: {
    $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [-0.02028, 51.50703]
      },
      $maxDistance: 3000 // 3k I'm assuming
    }
  }
});

print(collection.length()); // I get 6 (which is round about right)
```

Here's my Mongoose script:

```
MyModel
  .find()
  .where('geo')
  .near({
    center: [-0.02028, 51.50703],
    maxDistance: 3000,
    spherical: yes
  })
  .exec(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log(results.length); // Here I get over 340, which I think is all of the possible results.
    }
  });
```

As you can see, the result count is entirely different. In fact, changing the `maxDistance` property in the Mongoose script seems to do nothing.

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: I've just found that doing the query directly inside of the `.find()` method works. So there must be a problem in the Mongoose `Query` builder.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you are missing here.

According to the mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/maxDistance/) maxDistance is in meters only if your center is GeoJSON object.

So when you query with maxDistance: 3000, your unit is radian, and you get all of the results. (Since radian difference cannot go up to 3000).

Here is a working query with mongoose's query builder, and in meters:

```
MyModel
  .find()
  .where('geo')
  .near({
    center: {type: 'Point', coordinates: [-0.02028, 51.50703]}, // <--
    maxDistance: 3000,
    spherical: yes
  })
  .exec(function (err, results) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      console.log(results.length); // This should work.
    }
  });
```